# sendSMS no longer launches to the SMS app

Tags: codenameone

I have been developing and testing an app to update to the google play store as requested in this ongoing issue [Google Play recent review notification - APK HAS A PROMINENT DISCLOSURE BUT THE DISCLOSURE IS NOT ADEQUATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68921544/google-play-recent-review-notification-apk-has-a-prominent-disclosure-but-the)

Whilst testing the app I have noticed that `Display.getInstance().sendSMS(phoneNumber, message, true);` no longer opens the default SMS app of the device. Previous builds before at least the 23rd of August last week did not have this issue and would open the phone permission prompt for the user to allow before launching to the SMS app. `Display.getInstance().dial(phoneNumber);` still works however. Has there been any recent change server side that would affect this? Will I need to add the permission manually somehow? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're still dealing with the problem in the [Google Play recent review notification - APK HAS A PROMINENT DISCLOSURE BUT THE DISCLOSURE IS NOT ADEQUATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68921544/google-play-recent-review-notification-apk-has-a-prominent-disclosure-but-the) issue so we're investigating a lot of things including the phone permission which we disabled by default to avoid a case of accidental activation.

To explicitly enable this you will now need the build hint `android.readPhoneState=true`.

Comment: Hi thank you for the support, unfortunately adding this build hint hasn't invoked any permission requests. Is there anywhere else I need to go to enable the hint?

Comment: Using "android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE=true" I am able to enable the phone permission. However the SMS app still does not launch unfortunately

Comment: I can confirm add this key for the build hint has resolved the issue "android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE=true". The SMS app is now launched. Thank you for your help as always

Comment: I'm guessing this is related to something that broke in moving to the newer API level but that happened much sooner.