# I got warnings when upload to Google Play

Tags: codenameone

I got warnings when I upload cn1 Android build to Google Play.

The warning messages are below.

[image]

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
     implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:12.0.1'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:12.0.1'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12.0.1'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.1'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.1'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.1'
 implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:4.0.0'
 implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'co.infinum:goldeneye:1.1.2';
}
```

Comment: Which ad library dependencies are you using in Maven? Are you using the full screen ads or something else?

Comment: I don't have any ads in my app.
I don't use Maven.
I check the build hints of my app but without any key related to ads. 
How do I check the ad library dependencies?

Comment: Can you add your build hints from the properties file?
Only the android.* related ones.

Comment: I attached the keys related to android.* as an image in question.

Comment: I'll need the values too for those that accept something other than numbers or boolean values. You can copy and paste them from the codenameone_settings.properties file.

Comment: Also this might be related to an older version you had on play that did include those issues but is in the beta or alpha channel. Even if it's closed or "deleted" Google might still reject new releases because of that nonsense and is very unclear about that. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68931495/756809

Comment: I sent the codenameone_settings.properties through cn1 chat.
This issue happens since last month but I don't change any settings since then.

Comment: I looked through it and didn't see something immediately wrong. I've asked Steve to check.

Comment: Steve replied to me. He said it would be an older version issue. But my app doesn't have any build hint about ads in any release.

Comment: I saw a flurry build hint. I didn't see anything related to the android version but there's some iOS stuff there. But I agree with Steve I couldn't find anything that would make sense there.

You never uploaded a beta or alpha version of your app in the past?

Comment: Yes, I have beta and alpha versions of my app in the past. What can I do now? Should I publish a new release to all the alpha and beta channels?

Comment: I try to upload a new release of my app to internal testing. It also produces the issue. Pls. see the attached image in the question.

Comment: If you unzip the apk file and look within in the manifest xml file. Does it include mention of ads? What's listed there?

Comment: I unzip the apk file but I can't find manifest.xml file. Only AndroidManifest.xml which is not pure text file in the main directory. MANIFEST.MF in a subdirectory META-INF. I can't find any keywords related to ads in both of the files. Which file is the one you mention?

Comment: Yes that's the file I meant.  It doesn't seem to include any ad dependency which strengthens the theory that this is some garbage in the beta track or some other weird google play oddity.

Comment: This app doesn't include any ads in any version, but there is another app that includes ads features that are unpublished. Do you think this is a problem? I don't know how to do. Would you describe more clearly the solution in your reference doc

"The solution is to go one by one to the internal, alpha, beta channels and promote a release then finally publish to production."

Comment: I saw that this specific app had flurry in the past since it's still there in iOS. So I'm guessing an older version had it and is still somewhere in the alpha channel. I wrote about this a bit more [here](https://dev.to/codenameone/google-play-kafkaesque-experience-mp3). You need to upload a new alpha version of the app. Then promote it to beta. Then promote that to production. This purges the content of all the channels.

Comment: Do you mean the processes below?
Internal testing->Closed testing->Open testing->Production?

Comment: It doesn't work for me.  After promoting all the channel, I still get the warning.
The developer of Google Mobile Ads (GMA) SDK (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads) has reported version 12.0.1 as outdated. Consider upgrading to one of the following versions before publishing a new release: 19.2.0+.

Would you update GMA SDK to 19.2.0+ in your side(cn1 server)?

Comment: Can you send a build with include source and check the Android source code returned? It shouldn't have any mention of ads within it. If it does then where would that be?

Comment: How do I check the mention of ads? Would you provide some keywords for checking the mention of ads?

Comment: Just search for the word ads in the project in any file. It should be pretty obvious if it's there since this is the project that generates the binary.

Comment: Yes, I find the word ads in a section in build.gradle. 
I attach the section to the question.

Comment: Yes, I find the word ads in a section in build.gradle. I attach the section to the question. 

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.1'

Comment: There are also some files containing 'ads'.
Ads.java, Form.java......

Comment: That doesn't matter. What seems to be the problem is the `build.gradle` entry. We'll look into it.

Comment: Try setting `android.includeGPlayServices=false` to disable the default google play entries. Notice it might impact other requirements which you will need to add individually. Which libraries/features do you use?

Comment: I don't know what libraries/features I use. How do I check it? Would you revise it in cn1 build server? I think you have to check the SDK version on your side.

Comment: You can explicitly set the version with a build hint. But did you just try disabling as I mentioned? Do you use push? Location? Or anything like that in your app?

Comment: I don't use either push or location. I don't use special features. I got no warnings after setting android.includeGPlayServices=false. Will this impact the payment feature?
I have features about com.codename1.payment.*.

Comment: You would need to add the build hint `android.playService.base=true` and `android.playService.auth=true`. This might require adding a newer `android.playServicesVersion` as well. I'm checking to see what value would be correct there.

Comment: Why is it seems so complicated? Am I the only one who has this issue? My app doesn't have special features. Why should I have to add or modify these build hints?  Would you prepare these build hints as default in cn1?

Comment: I think the warning is new and most people don't look at warnings. You also hit the default legacy behavior of including multiple play libraries you don't need which was meant to ease migration. If you explicitly add the libraries you need that should solve the issue. You can set `android.playServiceVersion=16.0.0` to solve the issue.

Comment: Should I add all three build hints below:
android.playService.base=true
android.playService.auth=true
android.playServiceVersion=16.0.0

Comment: Yes. Those should solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, those solve the problem. Thank you.

Comment: I got errors from cn1 build server error log today. I added the four required build hints.   
android.includeGPlayServices=false
android.playService.base=true
android.playService.auth=true
android.playServiceVersion=16.0.0

Errors
Cause 3: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.0.
Required by:
    project : > com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0 >     project : > com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:15.0.1

Comment: Try removing the playServiceVersion, next week we hope this will be finally resolved, see [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/cn1/comments/11cmkp9/changes_to_android_play_services_versions/).

Comment: We pushed a fix last week but reverted it after it caused some builds to fail. We will probably have to bite the bullet and make those builds fail at some point.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand. Will the issue be solved in these weeks? Thank you.

Comment: Yes. We fixed it already in the code as you can see [in our git](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/b723c9edcaf42699db60326f9ae90a151bdba152). You can also follow Steve's discussion on the related complexities [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/cn1/comments/11cmkp9/changes_to_android_play_services_versions/)

Comment: Should I add back the 4 build hints for building?
android.includeGPlayServices=false
android.playService.base=true
android.playService.auth=true
android.playServiceVersion=16.0.0

Comment: This is just a warning so you don't need to be concerned about it. It will get fixed before it becomes an error. I would only include `android.playService.base=true` and `android.playService.auth=true` which are hints you would need anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update versions of the implemented dependencies in the Gradle of the project. Eg change

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1'

To

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.3.0'

Comment: This isn't correct for codename one applications. Notice the tag on the question.

Comment: I mean updating dependencies of generated android gradle project

Comment: Eg in the last comment of the following thread
https://www.reddit.com/r/cn1/comments/xilgeh/failed_to_send_push_notification/

Comment: Hi Shai, do you have the answer to this question?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Android builds can be troublesome at times due to Gradle versions used and sometimes all it takes is to uses latest Gradle versions as shown in threads below

Updating Gradle & classpath versions

https://www.reddit.com/r/cn1/comments/xy1ep8/android_build_with_android_archive_aar_library/

Building successfully using latest Gradle dependencies

https://www.reddit.com/r/cn1/comments/xilgeh/failed_to_send_push_notification/