# Is AdmobFullScreen.cn1lib outdated?

Tags: admob, codenameone, fullscreen

I made an app, using codenameone, that shows fullscreen ads. I used the library: AdmobFullScreen.cn1lib (ver:2). The app is published (android) and it works fine, and the ads work fine too. But when I published the app on Google Play Console, I got the following message:

> The developer of Google Mobile Ads (GMA) SDK (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads) has reported version 12.0.1 as outdated. Consider upgrading to one of the following versions before publishing a new release: 19.2.0+. Learn more about the SDKs that you're using and make informed SDK choices with Google Play SDK Index.

> The developer of Google Mobile Ads (GMA) SDK (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads) added the following note to SDK version 12.0.1: This version is officially deprecated, and will soon disable ad loading. Please update to a new version. See https://developers.google.com/admob/android/deprecation for more details.

So it seems that the library AdmobFullScreen.cn1lib is outdated. My question is: is there a new library for fullscreen ads in cn1, that is not outdated ? How can I solve this problem ? I would also appreciate some info about: how other people implement fullscreen ads in codenameone ?

I searched the web , but I didn't find anything that solves my problem.

Comment: This is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75342936/i-got-warnings-when-upload-to-google-play). The fix is already delivered but due to compatibility issues we reverted it. Hopefully it will go out this weekend.

Comment: Thank you Shai for your reply. It is encouraging to hear that there will be a fix very soon. Where will it be published ?